# .bin object executable in command prompt but not in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, binaryfiles

I have the following Practica1.cpp file:

```
// Ejemplo de la ordenacion por burbuja sobre un vector de enteros

#include <cstdlib> // Para usar srand y rand
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // Para usar ficheros
using namespace std;

void OrdenaBurbuja(int *v, int n);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int *v;
    int n, i, argumento;
    chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> t0, tf; // Para medir el tiempo de ejecución
    double tejecucion; // tiempo de ejecucion del algoritmo en ms
    unsigned long int semilla;
    ofstream fsalida;

    if (argc <= 3) {
        cerr<<"\nError: El programa se debe ejecutar de la siguiente forma.\n\n";
        cerr<<argv[0]<<" NombreFicheroSalida Semilla tamCaso1 tamCaso2 ... tamCasoN\n\n";
        return 0;
    }

    // Abrimos fichero de salida
    fsalida.open(argv[1]);
    if (!fsalida.is_open()) {
        cerr<<"Error: No se pudo abrir fichero para escritura "<<argv[1]<<"\n\n";
        return 0;
    }

    // Inicializamos generador de no. aleatorios
    semilla= atoi(argv[2]);
    srand(semilla);

    // Pasamos por cada tamaÒo de caso
    for (argumento= 3; argumento<argc; argumento++) {

        // Cogemos el tamanio del caso
        n= atoi(argv[argumento]);

        // Reservamos memoria para el vector
        v= new int[n];

        // Generamos vector aleatorio de prueba, con componentes entre 0 y n-1
        for (i= 0; i<n; i++)
            v[i]= rand()%n;

        cerr << "Ejecutando Burbuja para tam. caso: " << n << endl;

        t0= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // Cogemos el tiempo en que comienza la ejecuciÛn del algoritmo
        OrdenaBurbuja(v, n); // Ejecutamos el algoritmo para tamaÒo de caso tam
        tf= std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); // Cogemos el tiempo en que finaliza la ejecuciÛn del algoritmo

        unsigned long tejecucion= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(tf - t0).count();

        cerr << "\tTiempo de ejec. (us): " << tejecucion << " para tam. caso "<< n<<endl;

        // Guardamos tam. de caso y t_ejecucion a fichero de salida
        fsalida<<n<<" "<<tejecucion<<"\n";


        // Liberamos memoria del vector
        delete [] v;
    }

    // Cerramos fichero de salida
    fsalida.close();

    return 0;
}


void OrdenaBurbuja(int *v, int n) {

    int i, j, aux;
    bool haycambios= true;

    i= 0;
    while (haycambios) {

     haycambios=false; // Suponemos vector ya ordenado
     for (j= n-1; j>i; j--) { // Recorremos vector de final a i

         if (v[j-1]>v[j]) { // Dos elementos consecutivos mal ordenados
          aux= v[j]; // Los intercambiamos
          v[j]= v[j-1];
          v[j-1]= aux;
          haycambios= true; // Al intercambiar, hay cambio
         }
     }
    }
}
```

so I compile it like this:
`g++ -o Practica1.bin Practica1.cpp -std=c++11`
Then I get my Practica1.bin
However when I try 
`.\Practica1.bin 12345 1000 2000 3000`
It just opens a corrupt written file

If I compile it like a .exe:
`g++ -o Practica1.exe Practica1.cpp -std=c++11`
I get the desired output:
`.\Practica1.exe 12345 1000 2000 3000`:

```
Ejecutando Burbuja para tam. caso: 2000
        Tiempo de ejec. (us): 11853 para tam. caso 2000
Ejecutando Burbuja para tam. caso: 3000
        Tiempo de ejec. (us): 27954 para tam. caso 3000
```

On the other hand, on the cmd I can create the same .exe or .bin as before, and both will compile with:

`Practica1.bin salida.txt 12345 1000 2000 3000`
or `Practica1.exe salida.txt 12345 1000 2000 3000`

but without the ./

Of course I tried to compile from Visual Studio Code the .bin without the ./ and it doesn't work

I get better results with the .bin logically, so I think this is important

So I want to know if it is possible to execute .bin files from Visual Studio Code

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.\xyz` will _open_ a file, not neccesarily execute it. `.exe`-> executable program -> run it, `.bin` -> binary data file -> open in editor. Why do you think the filename extension would change anything in your program? Why should it be better if it's named .bin?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using Windows because you are compiling an exe, maybe unix systems behave likewise.

`.\xyz` will try to *open* file `xyz`, not neccessarily execute it. So Windows will treat the file according to it's extension.

In `.\Practica1.exe 12345 1000 2000 3000` Windows recognizes the file as executable, because of the extension `.exe`, so it will run the program.

However when opening `.\Practica1.bin 12345 1000 2000 3000` Windows thinks it's a binary data file because of the extension `.bin` and tries to open it in the according program, which happens to be a text-editor on your system.

That should explain the first confusion. Now, the extension of a file does not matter when executing. Simply compile as `.exe` and be happy with it.